# why do two pages, 100% the same code, both including the same style.css have different output?

Tags: php, html, css

i had a strange situation where a function that prints the navigation section of the website, was giving slightly different output on one page than the other. first started when i was adding  which i didnt have declared before. the function that prints the navi was given the same arguments on both pages. yet one page was outputting it with extra breaks or extra margins or something.

so i spent alot of time messing with the style.css but no matter what, the one page always had more space in between the links. changing the style effected both pages but the one page always had more spacing or margins or breaks or whatever it is.

then i made sure both pages had no xml validation errors, made it perfect in that sense, still the one page had more spaces between the links.  WHEN THE EXACT SAME FUNCTION TO PRINT THE NAVI IS BEING CALLED...

finally I had had it, i copied all of page a's code (the page displaying properly) and i pasted it into page b's code (pasting over b's old code) and i saved and to my jaw dropping awe, page b is STILL SHOWING WITH EXTRA SPACES.

to be clear, 2 files, code in the files is 100% identical only the name of the documents are different. and yet the output on the one is still double spaced. And i repeat again, both files loading the same style.css and yet output is different...

someone PLEASE let me know how this is possible. and better yet how to fix it.

i dont really see how code example is necessary with all being said but i'll give you the function that prints the navi

```
    function navigation ($str){
    settotals(0);
    if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "eng")
    {   
    $home = "Home";
    $login = "Login";
    $insert = "Insert";
    $post = "Post Request";
    $ranks = "Ranks";
    $score = "Scoreboard";
    $register = "Register";
    $howtoread = "Read Japanese";
    $contact = "Contact Us";
    $engreq = "English Requests";
    $japreq = "Japanese Requests";
    $japtra = "Japanese Translations";
    $engtra = "English Translations";
    $mytran = "My Translations";
    $mylikes = "My Likes";
    $likesrec = "Likes Received";
    $pref = "Preferences";
    }
    else
    {
    $home = "ホーム";
    $login = "ログイン";
    $insert = "入力";
    $post = "リクエストを掲示";
    $ranks = "ランク";
    $score = "スコアボード";
    $register = "登録";
    $howtoread = "日本語の読み方";
    $contact = "コンタクト";
    $engreq = "英語のリクエストリスト";
    $japreq = "日本語のリクエストリスト";
    $japtra = "英和訳リスト";
    $engtra = "和英訳リスト";
    $mytran = "自分の翻訳リスト";
    $mylikes = "「いいね」を押したリスト";
    $likesrec = "「いいね」をもらったリスト";
    $pref = "選択肢";
    }
    ?>
    <img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/blankbutton.jpg" width="152" height="26"/>    <p><font face="Arial" size="4">
        <a href="http://mrhowtosay.com">&nbsp;<?echo $home?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>login">&nbsp;<?echo $login?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
        <?if ($_SESSION['rights'] >= 4)
       {?>
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>insert" >&nbsp;<?echo $insert?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
    <? }?>
    <a href="<? echo $str; ?>search" >&nbsp;<?echo $post?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />    
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>ranks">&nbsp;<?echo $ranks?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>score">&nbsp;<? echo $score?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>register">&nbsp;<?echo $register?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>read">&nbsp;<?echo $howtoread?></a><br /><img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/line.gif" width="137" height="1"><br />
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>contact">&nbsp;<?echo $contact?></a><br />
        </font>
        <font face="Arial" size="2">
 <br />
    <img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/Browse.gif" width="152" height="26"><br /><br />

    &nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>   <a href="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=1&amp;pagenum=1&amp;set=1#down">&nbsp;<?echo $engtra?></a><br /><br />

    &nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/><a href="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=2&amp;pagenum=1&amp;set=1#down">&nbsp;<?echo $japtra?></a><br /><br />

       <img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/new.gif" width="152" height="26"><br />
  <br />
  &nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>  
        <a href="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=3&amp;pagenum=1&amp;set=1#down">    <?echo $engreq?></a> 
        <br /><br />
 &nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>  
   <a href ="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=4&amp;pagenum=1&amp;set=1#down"><?echo $japreq?></a>
  <br /><br />


  <?if ($_SESSION['username'])
{ ?>
<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/promo.gif" width="152" height="26"><br /><br />

&nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>   <a href="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=5&amp;set=1&amp;pagenum=1&amp;user=<?echo $_SESSION['username'];?>#down"><?echo $mytran?></a>

<br /><br />&nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>   <a href="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=6&amp;set=1&amp;user=<?echo $_SESSION['username'];?>#down"><?echo $mylikes;?></a>


<br /><br />&nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>   <a href="<? echo $str; ?>translated?mode=7&amp;set=1&amp;user=<?echo $_SESSION['username'];?>#down"><?echo $likesrec;?></a>


<br /><br />&nbsp;<img border="0" src="<? echo $str; ?>img/arrowleft.gif" width="11" height="11"/>   <a href="<? echo $str; ?>preferences"><?echo $pref?></a>

      <?
}
?></font></p>
  <font face="Arial" size="2"><?
  if ($_SESSION['username'])
  signature($_SESSION['username'],"");?></font><br />
  <?
 }
```

Comment: Can you post links to the sites?

Comment: If the files are exactly the same as you say, I'm not sure what's going on. Have you actually diffed them, or proved the point by copying one file over the other (rather than just copying and pasting its contents)? In addition, your HTML is from the time dinosaurs roamed the earth (the font tag was deprecated last millenium) and you're trying to use an html5 doctype, so who knows what could happen. I'd spend time sorting out your HTML first.

Comment: Do both pages have the same encoding? If you copied the php file content, you should check, how the editor encoded your file while saving. A tool like notepad++ is able to show the used encoding.

Comment: page a - http://mrhowtosay.com/translated page b - http://mrhowtosay.com/      note that viewed via firefox the pages seem the same, any other browser, you see the spaces in the navigation

Comment: viewing the source of both pages, you see that they are 100% the same. which means the output of the print navi function was the same in both cases

Comment: yes both pages have the same encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that your problem has indeed to do with UTF-8. I analyzed your example pages with firebug, and it revealed, that the html pages contain the **UTF-8 BOM-header**, but the untranslated page contains it twice!

These 3 characters ( ï»¿) at the begin of the file are written by your editor, but they won't be displayed. With a HEX-editor you can see the difference, you can also go to the file properties and look at the file size, you will notice that they differ slightly.

My recommendation would be, to save the files as UTF-8 **without** BOM-header. Especially the double header makes the IE to switch to the quirks-mode (you can press `F12` to get the developer tools in IE to see it), and that causes the different rendering. A double BOM-header is wrong in any case.

EDIT:

Just found a wonderful tool for [checking utf-8 BOM and header](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) problems.

Comment: I believe this is indeed the problem, would repasting the content of the documents into new documents and saving over the old documents remove the BOM-header? or would it be copied over in the paste?

Comment: i was able to remove the bom header, and it has fixed the problem thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

1.) Calling the same function with the same arguments does *not* neccessarily produce the same output. There might be other factors that influence the output, like environment variables, software versions, and and and.

So not the fact that the function is called the same way is of interest, but *only* if the output is *really* identical. Did you check that? You don't mention that...

2.) The fact that on both pages you add the same style definition file does *not* mean the the wohle style definition is identical on both sites. Other style definitions might interfere. First, obviously the browsers builtin style rules might be different and then there might other style files be included. Such situations are always crusial to the order in which they are included. If some other style definition gets validated *after* your styles then the result may well come out different.

You will have to check the actual result you see using a browser builtin debugger.

Comment: you don't need a debugger in the browser, view source is already helpful. but anyway +1.

Comment: @hakre: it certainly is helpful, but if you want to understand thstyle effect ot certainly is not sufficient. You need some kind of console that allows to view which rules are actually applied.

Comment: console =/= debugger. you mean DOM inspection and CSS inspection etc. debugger = for programming languages, running code, like javascript.

Comment: look at the links to the 2 pages, view source and the pages are 100% the same, yet viewed with IE or Chrome or safari, one page has spaces in the navigation links the other does not...

Answer (score 0):

If the same function with the same input is giving different output the function is a so called [*nondeterministic* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm).

Because if a function is non-deterministic, this is often not useful because you can not use it in a deterministic way (e.g. I have a problem A, I use function F than can deal with problem A, fine unless F is not clear what it does).

Therefore these uncertainties of making a function nondeterministic are often flaws which can lead to failure of the application. Or just different output as in your case.

This can happen because of hidden dependencies (e.g. there is an encoding parameter injected to a function you use inside that function that is specified via php.ini) or static state (the HTTP request differs so that the output of the function differs in the context of HTTP request and response of Browser and Server).

Answer (score 0):

The function is not the problem here. On one of the pages, you specified the `DOCTYPE` and you forgot to do it on the other one. That's why it's interpreted by the browser differently. Remember to ALWAYS add the `DOCTYPE` to your pages (except when your code is in HTML5 and in XML notation).
So, add:

```
<!doctype html>
```

on the top of every page, so the rendering will be the same as on the `http://mrhowtosay.com/translated` page. Then apply some aesthetic changes if you need to. If you stick to pages with no `DOCTYPE` specified, you can never really be sure what will the output look like and there is a GREAT chance that it will be different on a different browser.

Comment: i guess you missed the part where viewing the source, both files have 100% the same code. that includes the doctype declaration. both pages have it, yet one page has different output. the links to pages are in the question comment

Comment: I inspected the source with Developer Tools in Chrome when answering, and I didn't see the doctype on page b. I see that you managed to fix the problem with another answer and doctype is properly read by the browser now.